# Generate string from 00:00:00 to FF:FF.FF in php

Tags: php, hex, counting

I need to generate and echo values from `00:00:00` to `FF:FF.FF` like for counting from `1` to `1000000`. I know with numbers but how with hexadecimal numbers?
for example I need this at echo:

```
 00:00:00
 00:00:01
 00:00:02
 .
 .
 .
 FF:FF:00
 FF:FF:01
 FF:FF:02
 .
 .
 .
 FF:FF:FF
```

How to do this in PHP?

Comment: You might look at dechex(). And maybe some nested WHILE loops. Try something and show us the code. Its kind of a fun problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP accepts integer literals in hexdecimal format, so you'd just be iterating from `0` to `0xFFFFFF`. For each iteration, you could convert the integer to decimal format, left-pad it with zeroes and then split every to character and implode with `:` to get the format you want:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; ++$i) {
    echo implode(':', 
    str_split(str_pad(strtoupper(dechex($i)), 
      6, 
      '0', 
      STR_PAD_LEFT), 
    2)) . 
    '<br>';
}
```

Comment: The 8 from the str_pad should be 6. --> FF:FF:FF instead of FF:FF:FF:FF

Comment: No problem, I was writing the answer myself but just saw you posted this ;)